# Synch NetSuite SuiteScript Files with Git Repo

Tags: eclipse, git, netsuite

We're trying to use Git source control for our NetSuite SuiteScript.  How can I synch my Eclipse SuiteScript workspace files with my local git repo if the local repo already contains the files (meaning "Share Project" won't work)?

I've already setup a Git Repo for our NetSuite SuiteScript library.  The initial setup was simple because I pulled down our file cabinet using the SuiteCloud IDE (Eclipse/NetSuite bundle), added an existing local git repo, and used the Eclipse Team > Share Project feature to push the SuiteScript files to the repo.  However, that method only works the first time through.

Our other developers aren't able to use the Share Project feature to synch the projects with the Repo since the files already exist in both locations.  The challenge is that the files need to be pulled directly from NetSuite first in order to have the necessary indexes for the File Cabinet.

Comment: You can also try http://suitecoder.appspot.com/ . Though it only provides a subset of Git features but It has it's own very powerful features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

1. Clone your remote repo (can use init too but easier with clone IMO)
2. Delete all the files in your repo
3. Pull all the files into Eclipse from NetSuite.
4. Use Team > Share Project to synch with your repo
5. Use fetch to reset to the remote repo

   ```
   git fetch
   git reset --hard origin/master
   ```

After this you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to pull files from file cabinet, do `git init` , commit files to git repo, and then delete the project from workspace. This would ensure the files exists in netsuite and git repo both.

Now, you can take a similar approach as in the case where files existed in both NetSuite and git repo, by creating new project and pulling up the files again from NetSuite and adding git repo info.